# proguard and R in android

Tags: android, manifest, proguard

I'm using proguard for the first time with my android app.

I'm not getting it working correctly. I was looking at my usage.txt file to see what was the part's that proguard deleted from my code.

I see this unusual things and didn't know what to think:

```
 [my_package].Manifest
    [my_package].Manifest$permission
    [my_package].R$array
    [my_package].R$attr
    [my_package].R$bool
    [my_package].R$color
    [my_package].R$dimen
    [my_package].R$id
    [my_package].R$integer
    [my_package].R$layout
    [my_package].R$menu
    [my_package].R$raw
    [my_package].R$string
    [my_package].R$style
    [my_package].R$styleable
```

Is proguard deleting all this content from my code?

Comment: Your program works after using proguard?

Comment: No, proguard is causing some errors on my app. I think is also because of some reflections i'm calling. I'm working with the keep option to avoid removing / renaming this methods and classes.

Comment: Yes, when we use reflection we must use keep option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proguard makes reflection with the R class in android application no longer work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923815/proguard-makes-reflection-with-the-r-class-in-android-application-no-longer-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your proguard configuration:

```
#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

and look at this for a generic android proguard setup: [Android: What are the recommended configurations for Proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068251/android-what-are-the-recommended-configurations-for-proguard)

EDIT:
For reflection add this:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
    <fields>;
}
```

Comment: That's already in `${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt` so you shouldn't need to specify that again.

Comment: I'm using: ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt so i think i already have this lines added

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923815/proguard-makes-reflection-with-the-r-class-in-android-application-no-longer-work